# Twitter bootstrap modal - change option for existing modal

Tags: twitter, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I want to change modal behavior after certain event.

```
$('.myModal').modal('show'); // default behavior - user can close modal on ESC
$(button).click(function(){
    $('.myModal').modal({keyboard:false}); // override 
                                           // prevous line code does not work as i expect,
                                           // user can close modal with ESC
    $('.myModal').data('modal').option.keyboard = false; // even this code doesn't work
});
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, i was using the wrong data...

Can you try with this (considering bt3) :

```
$('#myModal').data('bs.modal').options.keyboard=false;
```

**But**

It don't work if the modal is open, you need to refresh it.

Comment: Good point about using 'bs.modal' instead of 'modal'. This fixed the issue for me